# Set a php variable via ajax success response

Tags: php, ajax

Clicking a button does this(the button is located in cart.php):

```
  function send()
    {
    var data = $('#guid').val()
           $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "clc.php",
                    data: "guid="+data,
                    beforeSend: function(xhr){
            $("#result").empty();
           $('.loading').show();
       },
                    success: function(html) {
                            $("#result").empty();
                            $("#result").append(html);
                    },
                    complete: function(xhr, textStatus){
            $('.loading').hide();
       }
            });
```

It sends stuff to this php script:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['guid']!='')
{
  $guid = $_POST['guid'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'someurlblablabla');
$content = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($content, true);

foreach($result[tariffs] as $p)
{
  if($p[urgency]=='Срочная'){
    if($p[maxPeriod]==0)
    {
      $srok = 'Уточните у службы доставки';
    }
    else
    {
      $srok = $p[minPeriod].' - '.$p[maxPeriod].' дн.';
    }
echo '<h3><p>Тип доставки: '.$p[name].'</p><p>Срок: '.$srok.'</p><p>Стоимость: <b>'.$p[total].' руб.</b></p></h3>';
}
}
}
?>
```

Now i need to use $p[total] back in the cart.php script as some $variable to do calculations. Something like this:

```
$totalPrice += $p[total];
$order->setTotalPrice($totalPrice);
```

Is this even possible to set a php variable via ajax success response?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is possible only when js and php code on same page!

Comment: well they are on the same page in cart.php

Comment: then add those php variable in success enclosed with PHP tages.

Comment: [Why is `$foo[bar]` wrong?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar)